# how can i get the content of a class in selenium webdriver?

Tags: html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**code :**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\bji\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data") #e.g. C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Default') #e.g. Profile 3
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\bji\Downloads\chromedriver_win32(1)\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)






driver.get('wanted website')

content = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__layout"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a/div[3]/div[2]/div/p')


if ( content == 24 ) :
    content.click()
```

**and this my html code :**

```
<p data-v-d31307be="" class="tw-ml-2 text__green">24</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `.text` from Selenium.

```
content = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__layout"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a/div[3]/div[2]/div/p')
if content.text == "24":
   content.click()
```